# Transform - Skew anchor tag background only

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms, skew

Without changing the HTML, how can I make the text straight while keeping skew on the background only?

https://jsfiddle.net/z4ms6k07/1/

```css
.btn {
  transform: skewX(-59deg);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btn a {
  transform: skewX(59deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-one">
    <a href="#">BTN ONE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-two">
    <a href="#">BTN TWO</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skew the text back. Since transform doesn't work on non block elements, and `a` is an inline tag, you need to change the `a` tag `display` to `inline-block` or `block`:

```css
.btn {
  transform: skewX(-59deg);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btn a {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skewX(59deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-one">
    <a href="#">BTN ONE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-two">
    <a href="#">BTN TWO</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can almost swear I tried that :/ thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You actually did, but only `-9px`, and you haven't changed the display.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to `a` tag, that would make it work with the `transform` property. So in order to use the `transform: skew(-59deg)` you have to add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to `a` tag

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    transform: skewX(-59deg);
    background-color: yellow;
}
.btn a {
    transform: skewX(59deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-one">
        <a href="#">BTN ONE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-two">
        <a href="#">BTN TWO</a>
  </div>
</div>
```